# Match entries in column A with an entry in column B

Tags: excel

In my spreadsheet, column A has entries that could be repeated further down the column.

I want my entry in column B to repeat in every instance of a matching Column A entry.

Answer (score 0):

How I have it now is that column C is the one automatically updating after entries in column B are made.  Put this formula in cell C1 and drag it down:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1, $A$1:$B$100, 2, FALSE) <> 0, VLOOKUP(A1, $A$1:$B$100, 2, FALSE), "")
```

Edit: You can always change how many cells to look up by changing A2:A$100 to A2:A$n.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't describe it properly.  I have a list of text entries in Column A, some of them are repeated multiple times down Column A.  When I make an entry in Column B, I would like that entry to show up in Column B at every instance of matching Column A entry.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is working, thanks!  But, I noticed that it only works when I enter something into the first occurrence, is there a way to write the formula so that I can enter at any point down Column B and have it show in all occurrences?